# How do I go about proving if a|b then $a^n|b^n \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: proof-writing, induction, divisibility

I'm trying to prove that if a|b then $a^n|b^n, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I know $a|b \rightarrow b = aq, q \in \mathbb{Z}$ by the definition of divisibility.

I  can then (I think) exponentiate both sides to n, since they are equivalent.

$b^n = (aq)^n$

$b^n = a^nq^n$

From here I would assume that I use induction of some sort to prove this generally holds for $n \in \mathbb{N}$

But how do I even go about doing that? If I make the induction assumption that for an arbitrary $k \in \mathbb{N}$ that $a^k|b^k$ does that not imply that $b^k = a^kq$ for some $q \in \mathbb{Z}$?

I feel like I've ran into a contradiction in my thought process, before even really getting to the $k+1$ induction step and I don't know how to proceed. I don't know how I'd even begin to show this holds by induction, since I am not even sure what induction assumption I should be making at this point.

Any hints or help would be greatly appreciated to get me unstuck.

Comment: You don't need induction.  The statement $b^n=a^nq^n$ is already enough - you have $b^n$ equal to $a^n$ times an integer (why is $q^n$ and integer)?

Comment: @MichaelBurr I see what you mean. I think I've been so caught up in using inductive proofs I just assumed I had to in this case. To address what you said , I would assume that I could argue $q^n \in \mathbb{Z}$ because $q^n$ is simply q times itself n times, which would inherently be an integer by multiplicative closure of the integers then, right?

Comment: Yes, the product of integers is an integer.  So, you could use induction to prove that an integer times itself $n$-times is an integer, if you're really feeling that induction should appear somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let there be some integer $p$ such that $$p\cdot a=b$$ You want to an integer $q$ such that $$q\cdot a^n=b^n$$

$$b^n=(p\cdot a)^n=p^na^n$$

You've just shown $b^n$ to equal some integer $p^n$ times $a^n$. Note that $p^n$ is an integer because an integer to the power of a natural number is an integer.

---

If you want to, you can show that an integer, $p$, raised to the power of a natural number $n$, is always going to be an integer using induction.

**Base Case:** $n=1$

$p^1=p$ which is an integer

**Inductive Step:**

Assume that $p^k$ is an integer for some natural number $k$.

$$p^{k+1}=p^k\cdot p^1$$

An integer, $p^k$, times integer $p$ is going to be an integer.